# Why is my mail deleted when I drop the mail into a folder in SharePoint

Tags: email, sharepoint, outlook

When I drag and drop a mail from Outlook to Sharepoint Online document library then the mail is deleted in Outlook.

2 weeks ago it doesn't deleted.

Somethings changed in outlook365?
Now I must click on 'ctrl' if I want that my mail is not deleted

Answer (score 1):

Update 2023/5/17:

Just as I had Microsoft Support in a call the issue seems to have resolved itself, still verifying with end users if it still occurs on their end.

---

Old post:

We're experiencing the same thing, I have made a ticket with MS support in hopes of them acknowledging they changed something and changing it asap.

From what I can find there's multiple ways to handle drag and drop into a webapplication, one of them simply does a copy, one does a move (copy + delete). It appears a recent change on their end must have used the wrong type of action.

I found another recent post about this, without any resolution:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/drag-and-drop-works-however-deletes-email-can-we/865f60c3-7980-4465-8a19-4d60b0ae5aba

Answer (score 1):

Many customers are facing this issue due to latest updates by Microsoft.

Here are few related threads for this issue:

1. [E-mails are deleted when sharing to sharepoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1276122/e-mails-are-deleted-when-sharing-to-sharepoint)
2. [Drag and drop WORKS. However, deletes email. Can we fix?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/drag-and-drop-works-however-deletes-email-can-we/865f60c3-7980-4465-8a19-4d60b0ae5aba)

As per the 1st link, if you hold down the CTRL key as you drag the email from outlook to SharePoint, email stays in the outlook inbox and it will not be deleted.

I guess we have to use this workaround till Microsoft fixes this issue.

I will suggest you to raise a support ticket with Microsoft and report this behavior - [Get M365 support - online support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

You can also add feedback about this on relevant feedback portal at: [Microsoft feedback portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/)

Comment: I am checking the status of this case. Did Ganesh Sanap 's answer help you? Please let us know if you would like further assistance.
If you have any update about this issue, please feel free to post back.